# How disable Messenger vibration on iOS 14

Tags: ios, messages

I want to disable Messenger notifications from vibrating on my iPhone iOS 14, but keep them silent. How to do that? There doesn't seem to be an option for it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

First, open “**Settings.**”
In Settings, navigate to **“Accessibility.”**
In Accessibility, tap **“Touch.”**
In Touch settings, scroll down and tap the switch labeled **“Vibration”** to turn it off.

Comment: I don't see any *Vibration* option in **Settings > Accessibility > Touch** on ios 13? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @sfxedit, The question is about **iOS** 14 and it's there just as this answer states. If you do not see it in **iOS** 13 then it probably wasn't a feature in that release of **iOS**.

Comment: Ok, yeah I see that ios 14 has a new *Vibration* option - https://support.apple.com/en-afri/guide/iphone/iph77bcdd132/ios